# How to encode a CSV File Import?

Tags: c#, file, encoding, csv

I have this code :

```
string ABSfilePath = "";

CsvFileReader reader = null;
ABSfilePath = Server.MapPath("/myfile.csv");

try
{
    reader = new CsvFileReader(ABSfilePath);

    CsvRow myRow = new CsvRow();
    while (reader.ReadRow(myRow))
    {
        Response.Write(myRow[0].ToString()+"<br />");
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Response.Write(err.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (reader != null)
        reader.Dispose();
}
```

but when I try to import my file `myfile.csv`, some chars are "uncorrectly" encoded, like :

```
STATUA DELLA LIBERT�
```

So, how can encode this? Thanks

Comment: are you 100% sure that opening the file with notepad or notepad++ before the import shows you the correct char and not the funny symbol above?

Comment: opening with notepad++ I get STATUA DELLA LIBERT·

Comment: if the char is not there before then file has wrong encoding and is not about CSV parsing but about getting the file in correct format and encoding in the first place.

Comment: but on CSV is STATUA DELLA LIBERTÀ (which is correct)

Comment: ...and this is the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes! Should be "STATUA DELLA LIBERTÀ"

Comment: If I do copy and paste from CSV (opened with excel) to Notepad, it get the correct chars...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader = new CsvFileReader(ABSfilePath);
```

is the culprit. You should first open a StreamReader with the correct encoding (I suspect UTF-8),

```
StreamReader MyStreamReader = new StreamReader(ABSfilePath, System.Text.Encoding.WhateverYouNeed);
```

then do

```
reader = new CsvFileReader(MyStreamReader.BaseStream);
```

Comment: Edited my Answer to use `MyStreamReader.BaseStream`instead of `MyStreamReader`

Comment: Ok, tried with MyStreamReader.BaseStream! The problem still happens.. I try some other encoding..

Comment: No, neither with UTF8/7/32/UNICODE... :(

Comment: You should try `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-15")` but really you need to know which encoding your datasource is in!

Comment: When you save as CSV in Excel, I guess you will need to give a character Set. (Sorry, no Excel here, only OOo). But if it comes from Excel, `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-15")` or `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` seem good choices for the encoding.

Comment: You can't "know" from the CSV, but you can guess. The encoding is a property of the conversion, not of the file

Comment: OK, you your problem is not the CSV import into C#, but the CSV export from Excel (as you don't know the charset and can't influence it). While it would be tempting to advise you "Just use LibreOffice, you can give a charset there", please post the hex of the characters around LIBERTÀ and I'll guess for you.

Comment: PLEASE!! A bit more, and make sure you start with the L

Comment: LOL! sorry, but that's what I get : http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/8194/enck.png

Comment: À as B7 means "Codepage 850", So you need System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850)

Comment: Thanks! But, where do you get this info? so in the future I'll get them myself :)

Comment: What about Google? From knowing it is Excel, I knew it has to be something windows-specific. Together with the italian language the list of codepages was quite short, so I googled the character maps and looked, which one fit.

Answer (score 1):

What happens in your case is that the encoding of the CSV and the encoding of your page (html) do not match... you either make sure that both use the same encoding OR you convert the encoding of the CSV on reading. I don't know which class/library you use `CsvFileReader` but the easiest way would be to open the CSV with the correct encoding for example with a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) instead of `ABSFilePath` as parameter...

Answer (score 1):

You are using a non-standard class, I'll guess that you use [this one](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).  It is poorly designed, it doesn't let you change the encoding in any way.  You'll need to add a new constructor to fix that:

```
    public CsvFileWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding)
        : base(filename, encoding)
    {
    }
```

Now you can get it to read something else than just utf-8.  Best one to start with is Encoding.Default.